# Java, Making a class Immutable

Tags: java, immutability

I came across this exercise online where I have two classes and I'm supposed to make the `Tutor` class immutable. However, the only thing I can think of is adding `final` to `name` field. When it comes to the constructor, I don't think I need to change the initialisation of the `name` variable as `String` is immutable. I'm not sure how to approach the collection and how to make this part of the constructor immutable. **According to the exercise, I'm not supposed to change the Student class (which I can see is mutable)**

```
public class Student {    
    private String name;
    private String course;

    public Student(String name, String course) {    
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;    
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
}

public final class Tutor {
    private String name;
    private final Set<Student> tutees;

    public Tutor(String name, Student[] students) {
        this.name = name;
        tutees = new HashSet<Student>();
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
            tutees.add(students[i]);
    }

    public Set<Student> getTutees() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(tutees);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194139/make-immutable-java-object)

Comment: The tutors name can still be changed inside the tutor class itself so may not be considered immutable. Perhaps try making String name `final` as well. btw you should know that setting `final` on a class definition means the class can't be `extended`. doesn't make the class immutable though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Tutor` class presents many aspects promoting its immutability :

- the class is final
- the `Set<Student>` is protected against the modifications
- no method allowing to change directly the state of the class

However, the defensive copy of the constructor is not complete.
It also has to copy the `Student`s elements of the array passed. Otherwise the client of the constructor may change any instance of them and make so the `Tutor` instance mutable such as :

```
Student[] students = ...;
Tutor tutor = new Tutor(name, students);
students[0].setName("new Name!"); // break the immutability of Tutor
```

You should write something like :

```
public Tutor(String name, Student[] students){
  this.name = name;
  tutees = new HashSet<Student>();
  for (Student student : students){   
      Student copy = new Student(student.getName(), 
                                    student.getCourse());
      tutees.add(copy);
   }     
}
```

Additionally note that the `Set` returned by `getTutees()` is unmodifiable but elements contained in are as `Student` is mutable.
So to make Tutor immutable you also have to create a copy of the Student elements as you return `getTutees()` such as :

```
public Set<Student> getTutees(){
   Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
   for (Student student : tutees){
      Student copy = new Student(student.getName(), 
                                    student.getCourse());
      students.add(copy);
   }     
   return Collections.unmodifiableSet(students);
}
```

As you may notice, getting the immutability in these conditions (an instance that we wish immutable but that contains a collection referencing mutable instances) requires to write more code (to read/to maintain/to test) and to perform more processing (so slower to execute).
If `Student` was an immutable class, the original `getTutees()` and the original constructor would be enough.

Comment: I'd go one step further and store them all in a variable `Set<Student> studentSetParam` and then initialize the attribute like `tutees = Collections.unmodifiableSet(studentsSetParam)`.

Comment: This was my first thought, but it's still not really making the full state of `Tutor` immutable, it's just defending against changes to the set & the original student objects passed in. I could still call `getTutees()` and modify any of these copied instances. (Still, this may be what the assignment had in mind.)

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza  It is a possibility indeed.

Comment: thank you so much for you effort! However, in both the constructor and the getTutees method I cannot write Student student = new Student(); as Student object requires two parameters

Comment: @davidxxx thanks again, just to make sure - where we're using the getName() and getCourse() in both the constructor and the method - it should state student.getName() not students? :)

Comment: @mike231 Sure :)

Answer (score 2):

Proper way is to make an object immutable is to:

1. Declare the object final
2. Do not provide setter methods
3. Make all fields private
4. Make mutable fields final
5. Use deep copy in the constructor
6. Clone objects in getter methods, so you don't return actual reference.

Comment: *Clone objects in getter methods, so you don't return actual reference* if they're already immutable, it's not worth to return a copy.

Comment: I know the basic rules of Immutability,  I dont know how to make a defensive copy of tutees in the constructor

Comment: Well Greg is right, because anything that is not defined like `final type name = initvalue;` can be changed at runtime via reflection. `final` + `initialisation` may be introduced into the code as a constant, thus appearing as a constant in the code. so even if you changed it with reflection, the code would not react to it. but this behaviour is also javac and JVM specific...

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to return the Set of Students? If you really need that you can hide that by using an interface that provides only getters, something like

```
interface IStudent {
    public String getName();
    public String getCourse(); 
}

class Student : implements IStudent { ...}
```

and in your Tutor you return `Set<IStudent>`

Answer (score 0):

To make the Tutor class immutable, you should use the "final" modifier on all the fields inside a Tutor, not on the Tutor's class definition.

Answer (score 0):

### Java SE 16

You can use [JEP 395: Records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature, introduced as part of Java SE 16, to create an immutable class without requiring much ceremony.

If you have already gone through the above link, you must have figured out that you can do it simply as

```
record Tutor(String name, Set<Student> tutees) { }
```

What you get in turn are:

1. A `final class Tutor`.
2. A canonical constructor whose signature is the same as the header, `Tutor(String name, Set<Student> tutees)`.
3. `private final` fields, `name` and `tutees` and their corresponding `public` accessor method with the same name and return type.
4. Automatically created `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` methods.

#### Demo:

*Student.java*

```
record Student(String name, String course) { }
```

*Tutor.java*

```
import java.util.Set;

record Tutor(String name, Set<Student> tutees) { }
```

*Main.java*

```
import java.util.Set;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Student> cscStudents = Set.of(
                                            new Student("Harry", "Java-8"),
                                            new Student("Tina", "Java-9"),
                                            new Student("Andy", "Java-11")
                                        );

        Set<Student> scienceStudents = Set.of(
                                            new Student("Tony", "Phy"),
                                            new Student("Kerry", "Chem"),
                                            new Student("John", "Bio")
                                        );

        Tutor t1 = new Tutor("Mark", cscStudents);
        Tutor t2 = new Tutor("Robin", scienceStudents);
        Tutor t3 = new Tutor("Mark", Set.of(
                                            new Student("Andy", "Java-11"),
                                            new Student("Harry", "Java-8"),
                                            new Student("Tina", "Java-9")
                                        )
                            );

        System.out.println(t1);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(t1.tutees());
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Students of " + t1.name() + ":");
        t1.tutees()
            .stream()
            .forEach( t -> System.out.println(t.name()) );
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(t1.equals(t2));
        System.out.println(t1.equals(t3));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Tutor[name=Mark, tutees=[Student[name=Andy, course=Java-11], Student[name=Harry, course=Java-8], Student[name=Tina, course=Java-9]]]

[Student[name=Andy, course=Java-11], Student[name=Harry, course=Java-8], Student[name=Tina, course=Java-9]]

Students of Mark:
Andy
Harry
Tina

false
true
```