# How do I change the below code such that it prints “present” without changing the main function

Tags: java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class StudentTest {
    public static final class Student {
        public Student( String name ) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        private String name;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args ) {
        Map<Student, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put( new Student( "john"), "present" );
        System.out.println( map.get( new Student( "john" ) ) );
    }
```

I know how to make this work by changing the main function and initializing the object but is it possible to achieve the result without touching the main? I was asked this in an interview.

I have spent a lot of time googling but haven’t been able to get close to the answer. I’m not even sure what should be my search parameters anymore. Please help.

Comment: Hint: Look at the code for method `get` in class `java.util.HashMap`.

Comment: You need to implement `hashCode` and `equals` methods to achieve your lookup. And, also override `toString` to return name to print desired output.

Comment: Add the System.out.println() statement to your Student constructor?

Comment: Java SE 16 makes it easier to get rid of such a problem. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/65976915/10819573

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 different student object used while putting to and  getting from HashMap. So you were not able to print "present".

So you can override 2 methods in Student class, `equals` and `hashcode` such that when name is equal it `equals` should return true and `hashcode` should return same value.

That's it, your are done. You will get "present"

Overriding just equals is not fully correct answer. There is contract "Equal objects should always return same hashcode"

So overriding `equal and hashcode` is the clean way

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `equals(Object o)` method in class `Student`.
As default in java, the equals method just check if the objects are exactly the same, create with one `new` expression.
To change it, override the equals method to compare the name of the students.
For example:

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o instanceof Studet){
        return this.name.equals(((Student)o).name);
    }
    return false;
}
```

And, because of java contract, you should override `hashCode` like this:

```
public int hashCode(){
    return this.name.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, with the edit, this is answer is accurate as well. Worked perfectly. Note that your first snippet says `instaceof` instead of `instanceof` and `Studet` instead of `Student`